# sqlite3 Error Trying to Run: npm install sqlite3 --save (JS/Node in VSCode)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm, node-sqlite3

I'm following a Pluralsight Tutorial, trying to learn JS and Node.js but I'm running into trouble when running this in the terminal:

*npm install sqlite3 --save*

When I attempt to run that, I get this error:

PS C:\Users\nickc\Desktop\Code & Program Projects\JavaScript\JavaScript - Fundamentals\Section #9 - Modules\Multi-file JS Project> npm install sqlite3
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\nickc\Desktop\Code & Program Projects\JavaScript\JavaScript - Fundamentals\Section #9 - Modules\Multi-file JS Project\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! 'Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\nickc\Desktop@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp'
npm ERR!     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: []
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v18.15.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\nickc\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-30T15_10_56_173Z-debug-0.log

I was able to run this just fine:

*npm install sqlite --save*

Why am I having so much trouble trying to install sqlite3? I kind of need it to use a relational database with node.js but I can't move forward until I figure out why this is happening.

I was expecting it to install without any problems, such as when I installed sqlite using the terminal in vsCode.